# Elasticsearch plugin installation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a doubt in install plugin into elastic search. Instruction provided on github is not self explanatory for beginner. Please note that I am from .net background and trying to do setup in windows machine.

I am refering link https://github.com/dadoonet/fsriver/tree/es-1.x/#choose-scanned-directory and http://www.pilato.fr/fsriver/#autogenerated-mapping and trying to install FS River plug in.

Link says, In order to install the plugin, run:
bin/plugin -install fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river/fsriver/1.3.0

Please let me know where do I write this command and also if any other simple way available, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be ${ES_INSTALLATION}/bin/plugin -install fr.pilato.elasticsearch.river/fsriver/1.3.0.

`plugin.bat/plugin.sh  exist under ${ES_INSTALLATION}/bin`

Comment: please let me know the exact syntax to write in my command prompt.